# Issue with harvesthq's jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-chosen

While looking at various options for making dropdowns more user-friendly I came across this solution:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

In their first example (list of all countries) if you want to list all countries the names of which end with "ia", you get back: no results match "ia".
I imagine this would be a pretty common requirement for something with a search box.
Has anyone had a similar requirement and what is the solution?

Comment: Hi Alexander, the question is how do I get the plug-in to do a search with "contains"-like semantics instead of "begins with"-like semantics. I think the best way to understand what I mean is to actually visit the linked demo site and try out different search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Brendan's comment on http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen apparently works for version 0.9.8

Changed lines 738 and 739 to include ‘g’ for global and also took out the regexAnchor.

New lines look like this

```
regex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'gi');
zregex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'gi');
```

I have also included an anchor tag in my “no results” text which enables me to open a dialog to add a new item to the list and the refresh the list with the new object.